# What is the cost of implementing the Quantum Fourier transform in a classical computer?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, simulation, quantum-fourier-transform, space-complexity

What is the cost of implementing the Quantum Fourier transform (QFT) in a classical computer? We know we require at least $\log{n}$ depth quantum circuits to do a QFT in a quantum computer, with $n$ being the number of input qubits. Is there a similar result for classical computers?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform?

Comment: @MarkS: But FFT is not the classical version of QFT is it?

Comment: Yes, to run a classical version of, say, Shors algorithm, you could evaluate the periodic function for random inputs a number of times and hope for a collision, and use that collision to estimate the period. That would take exponential time..

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question currently lacks sufficient detail. For example, is the input classical or quantum? Is the objective to simulate QFT on a classical computer or is the goal to compute the Fourier Transform of some input sequence (the "Quantum" in "Quantum Fourier Transform" suggests the former, but the letter is more useful)?